# Django ORM - Fetch Multiple select_related having OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

My models structure is similar to this.

```
class Block(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = ( ('text', "TEXT"), ('image', "IMAGE"), ) // I have around 10 types
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=)

class User(models.Model):
    current_block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TextBlock(models.Model):
    block = models.OneToOneField(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='text', primary_key=True)

class ImageBlock(models.Model):
    block = models.OneToOneField(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='image', primary_key=True)
```

So, if I wanted to get the current_block of customer in a select related phrase, I use `Customer.objects.select_related('block', 'block__text', 'block__image')`. I have 10 block types similar to `text` and `image`, so my `select_related` clause is pretty big. Is there any way to get all the `blocks`?

Comment: Can please explain what you meant by `Is there any way to get all the blocks? `?

Comment: @ruddra e.g. I have 50 customers. 10 of them have TextBlock type blocks as current_block, 15 of them have ImageBlock as current_block and so on. So I want to fetch all my customers with all the current_blocks and the current_block.text or current_block.image fetched. This will allow me to use customer.current_block.text or customer.current_block.image without needing any additional queries.